# python-install script can't find pyenv locally

Tags: python, ubuntu, makefile, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a windows machine through WSL. I have cloned a H repository onto my machine and I need pyenv to control my python versions. I have successfully installed pyenv onto my machine and was able to install python 3.8.9 and verify its working through python --version and pyenv version. However, when I go to run a make file which runs a python-install script to make sure that I have the correct versions. It gives me the following errors:

`./bin/install-python: 30: pyenv: not found ./bin/install-python: 33: pyenv: not found ./bin/install-python: 35: pyenv: not found ./bin/install-python: 35: /versions/3.8.9/bin/pip: not found ./bin/install-python: 36: pyenv: not found`

I have updated my ~/.bashrc profile to include this:
`export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv" command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH" eval "$(pyenv init -)" eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"`

Yet, I still am not getting it to work.

Comment: Please use code block formatting not just backticks; it's very hard to read errors when they are wrapped like this.  Note that shell aliases are local to the shell.  They are not passed down to programs like make, etc. so declaring an alias in your current shell for `pyenv` is useless for running recipes in a makefile.